# Visual studio 2017 Live Unit Testing does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2017, live-unit-tests

Hello I'm getting a very strange exception (object reference not set to an instance of object) when using Visual studio 2017 Live Unit Testing if I run this test through Test Explorer->Run All all works fine and it’s also work in debugging but Live Unit Testing fall. [image]

[Test Project](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/eMIR6W6dUGcYOIVABIdIhlsZS0yWvF3LoXvI3OAk7rO?ref_=cd_ph_share_link_copy)

Comment: Let us know how if it worked .

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/56681/unable-to-run-tests.html