# Codelens disabled on last displayed file only but working fine on all other files of the C# project

Tags: c#, reload, codelens

VS Community 2019 v16.8.5. C#
Whenever VS 2019 starts and loads the last project, Codelens always not shown on the last displayed file alone. It is just blank, nothing, not even "references" or anything.
When I click on ALL other files, Codelens are working perfectly fine. It is just a problem for the last displayed file when I shut down VS 2019 previously.

I tried disable/enable and all other stuffs to refresh but just cannot get Codelens working on that particular last file.
However, if I do File>Close Solution and then reload the solution, Codelens suddenly working again on every single files.

It is just annoying because I need to open the project, close it and then re-open it again before I could do any coding.

Comment: I'll give you a tip to troubleshoot it, but it ain't pretty. Scroll through this giant question I wrote to the [answer where by the process of elimination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46208783/495455) I found a specific App.Config tag that causes Live Unit Testing to fail. Maybe you could do a Diff of your project between states and do a Compare?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem is kind of resolved in VS v16.9.2.
Codelens was still not shown properly on the last displayed file but once you start adding new codes to the file, Codelens just refresh itself and everything works fine afterward.